# How to use a complex key with IDBObjectStore.delete

Tags: javascript

I need to delete data and I'm trying to use IDBObjectStore.delete(id).  The problem is that the id I need to pass in is a complex key (i.e. ["first_id", "second_id"]).  It seems like it sort of silently fails and I'm not sure what's going on.

Does anyone know how to use the delete function with a complex key? Thanks in advance!